# How to query MongoDB for complex data

Tags: mongodb

I have a table structured as follows:

> db.l2vpn_fdb_database.findOne()

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId("5f5257f11324c04122714445"),
  hostname: "spine01-drt-red",
  l2vpn_fdb_database: {
    MAC: [
      {
        IfIndex: "1631",
        MacAddr: "00-00-0C-07-AC-01",
        SrvID: "1",
        VsiName: "EVPN",
      },
      {
        IfIndex: "0",
        MacAddr: "00-00-0C-07-AC-02",
        SrvID: "0",
        VsiName: "EVPN",
      },
      {
        IfIndex: "1631",
        MacAddr: "00-00-0C-07-AC-0A",
        SrvID: "1",
        VsiName: "EVPN",
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

I'd like to search for "MacAddr" object, could you help me figure out based on above? So essentially I'd like to be able to parse database for a MacAddress assuming it's there and be able to get "IfIndex" for further processing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$filter` to get matched objects

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      l2vpn_fdb_database: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$l2vpn_fdb_database.MAC",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.IfIndex",
              "1631"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kVnkVXqZxAK)**

Comment: would you know an example of how to do it using "find"?

Comment: If you don't need dupilcates https://mongoplayground.net/p/5o9QHEdtDvb ths helps. But be aware to use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_

Comment: thank you, what about hostname part? say i have multiple hostnames that had the same MacAddr (which is possible), how would i list all of the ones that have a particular MacAddr?

Answer (score 0):

for Hostname with macAddr try like this,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      l2vpn_fdb_database: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$l2vpn_fdb_database.MAC",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.IfIndex",
              "1631"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      hostname:{
          $eq:['$hostname','spine01-drt-red']
          }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

This query could help you.

```
b.l2vpn_fdb_database.findOne({
  "l2vpn_fdb_database.MAC.MacAddr": "00-00-0C-07-AC-01",
},
{
  "l2vpn_fdb_database.MAC.$": 1
})
```

The result is the same document just with 1 element in the array

Result:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5f5257f11324c04122714445"),
    "l2vpn_fdb_database": {
      "MAC": [
        {
          "IfIndex": "1631",
          "MacAddr": "00-00-0C-07-AC-01",
          "SrvID": "1",
          "VsiName": "EVPN"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```